# Insert a variable into SQLite database

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a function that inserts data into a SQLite database. I can manually add data using

```
sqlStatement.text = "INSERT INTO users (First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')";
```

This works perfectly. Now I am trying to insert the data from a variable instead. I can trace my variable from this function- `trace(Main._firstName); //returns John`, but when I insert it using this:

```
sqlStatement.text = "INSERT INTO users (First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES (" + Main._firstName + ", 'Doe')";
```

it inserts it as "null Doe". Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sqlStatement.text = "INSERT INTO users (First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES ('" + Main._firstName + "', 'Doe')";
```